# Emacs ignore \n in buffer

Tags: key-bindings, motion, newlines

I would like to change the default behavior in emacs when '\n' meta-characters are encountered by the cursor. The default behavior is such that at '\n',

(1) right-key sends the cursor to the beginning of the next line,
(2) up-key sends the cursor to the end of the prev line,
(3) down-key sends the cursor to the end of the next line.

How can I get emacs to ignore '\n' meta-characters in a given buffer? Or how can I get emacs to ignore either one of the keys identified in (1), (2) and (3)?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reassign the keys to new functions that don't move if the char at point is a newline:

```lisp
(defun maybe-down ()
  "Move down if char at point is not a newline."
  (interactive)
  (if (char-equal (char-after) 10) (ignore) (next-line)))
(define-key (current-local-map) [down] 'maybe-down)
```

And similarly for `[right]` with `(right-char)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This fails to run emacs 27. Fails `next-line` check. Fails define-key: `Wrong type argument: keymapp, nil`

Comment: The `nil` means there's no local map. You can define one, or turn on a major mode to establish one. I don't know what you mean by "fails next-line check".

Comment: Yes it's working as expected. Thank you. However, why do I get `Invalid function: (ignore)` when this condition gets satisfied:  `(if (char-equal (char-after) 10) ((ignore) (next-line)) (forward-char)))`

Comment: Seems I can ignore the `ignore next-line` completely and have just: `(if (char-equal (char-after) 10) () (forward-char)))`

Comment: @OS2: I wrote `(ignore)`, not `((ignore) ...`